# How to use Next.js for client rendering only

Tags: reactjs, next.js

https://github.com/zeit/next.js is "Framework for server-rendered React apps".

**My question:** is it possible to use it for client-rendered apps too? How?

**Why:**
I would like to take the frameworks benefits (code splitting via pages and hot reload) but I can't use a Node server.

**My research:**
What I've learned is that there is no single entry bundle that I would include in a html file. There's "hidden" `.next` folder that contains some bundles, but the code depends on some existing scripts probably rendered server-side.

Comment: To achieve client rendering like *create react app* you can try https://github.com/jaredpalmer/after.js which can be used either for CSR or SSR.

Comment: next.js offers static exports. I use this myself to host a complete website with React on an nginx server. No need for node. See https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible in v3 (currently in beta). The short version is that you create a config file that tells next what pages should be static, and then you run the command `next export`.

Read more about it at https://zeit.co/blog/next3-preview and https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/v3-beta#static-html-export

Answer (score 1):

**New Answer:**

I have a working next.js app running without the need for node. Use the export feature: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export

You can then host it on a CDN or a server.